# ServiceReference1.Service1Client' does not contain a definition for 'PutData'

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

MainPage.Xaml.cs

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Word_Meaning W2 = new Word_Meaning();

    W2 = Client.PutData(); - Where I am getting Error

    if (search.Text == W2.Word)
    {
        Content.Text = W2.Meaning;
    }
}
```

IService1.cs

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    Word_Meaning PutData();

}


[DataContract]
public class Wd
{

}
```

Service1.cs

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public Word_Meaning PutData()
    {
       //Code
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: I am trying to make A windows phone 8.1 Silverlight app which displays some data from sql using WCF.

Answer (score 0):

My guesses would be:

1. update your service reference in your project that has `MainPage.Xaml.cs` in it

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb628652.aspx
>
> Over time, the metadata for a WCF service may change, requiring that
>   the service reference be updated. To update a service reference In
>   Solution Explorer, right-click the service reference and then click
>   Update Service Reference. A progress dialog box is displayed while the
>   reference is updated from its original location, and the service
>   client is regenerated to reflect any changes in the metadata.

2. Make sure both your project that you are trying to build and your WCF service are built using the same .net versions
   more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: I tried updating and whatever you mention but no luck :(